# how do you debug Microsoft Media Platform on xbox?

Tags: silverlight-4.0, windows-media-player, xbox360

I am trying to run the sample Microsoft Media Platform plugins on the xbox (MMPPF.Addons).

I am able to compile the project in visual studion 2010 and deploy it to the xbox (I have a xbox debug box that supports lakeview platform.). I am able to run the application by double clicking "default.xex" in "Xbox neighborhood" or clicking "start without debugging" in visual studio.

However, I am unable to debug it by clicking "start with debugging". I got an error message saying "Unable to start program 'devkit:\MMPPF.Addons.Xbox\Debug\default.xex'".

I have installed the following software.

- visual studio sp1
- xdk 20871.1
- adk
- flash 14448.0
- silverLight 4
  I also have the xbox connected to both the internet and my computer.

Could anyone tell me what is missing?

Comment: Where did you download xdk 20871.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured out why. There seems to be something wrong with the debugger. I switched to the xbox native debugger and it worked. What I did was in the project property, debugger, pick the "xbox360 debugger" instead of the "xbox360 managed debugger".